# MySQL connection JDBC driver not found

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio, ojdbc

I am trying to open a MySQL connection but run into this error.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
```

There are plenty of questions online about this but I cannot seem to make it work.

I currently using gradle to `compile 'com.oracle:ojdbc14:10.2.0.4.0'` and I have added the connector library using the build in maven importer.

My code looks like this:

```
private static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.driver";

...

try {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER).newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
...
}
```

I tried to add ojdbc-14.jar to libs and reference that in gradle without success. I also use some groovy code in the build.settings but without success, I'm not sure how to work with that either.

A pic of my IDE:
[image: IDE screengrab]

Comment: Out of curiousity, why aren't you using sqlite?

Comment: @andrewdleach That is probably because me question about what DB to use got closed. In the LibGDX chat I decided I go with MySQL. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/108143/choosing-a-database-for-server-side?noredirect=1#comment188301_108143

Comment: The oracle driver jar contains the driver for the oracle database. Not for MySQL. Go to http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/. Is this an android app? Why do you use MySQL from an android app?

Comment: I have never used Gradle before nor the oracle driver but considering your using the `com.mysql.jdbc.driver` shouldnt you be using the mysql jdbc dependency? I dont see the `com.mysql.jdbc` package at all inside the Oracle JDBC dependency.

Comment: Lol... it was the uppercase D... Dunno where the comment went about that but I received that on my phone.

Comment: @JBNizet It is ultimately for an android app. But the android app connects to my server which is a basic java app.

Comment: @andrewdleach Since I finally got this working now. Could you enlighten me briefly on MySQL vs sqlite? How would that benefit over MySQL? I chosen MySQL eventually because I feel comfortable with it and it is very easy to migrate to any system or hosting service. I could even just run one on my current website domain and have less stress on the server that I will be running from home for the time being.

Comment: @MennoGouw I would suggest that you ask another SO question to get a better response. I only asked because sqlite is already incorporated in the Android Runtime Environment.

Comment: @ug_ I got this working now with `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` the connector is referenced as a External Lib .

Comment: @andrewdleach I'm not using android for connecting to MySQL. I use android to connect to my KryoNet server, a regular java app (using android studio). And only the server will query the database which "should" always be a local connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your DRIVER string. It should be

```
DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
```